# FormData is showing empty while appending the value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, form-data, recordrtc

I am using RecordRTC to record the voice and trying to send the recorded voice to server. Below is the code to store the blob and file name.

```
public uploadToServer(recordRTC, callback) {
    let blob = this.recordRTC instanceof Blob ? this.recordRTC : this.recordRTC.blob;
    let fileType = blob.type.split('/')[0] || 'audio';
    let fileName = (Math.random() * 1000).toString().replace('.', '');
    if (fileType === 'audio') {
      fileName += '.' + (!!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'ogg' : 'wav');
    } else {
      fileName += '.webm';
    }
    // create FormData
    var formData: FormData = new FormData();
    console.log(fileName);
    console.log(blob);
    formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
    formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);
    console.log(formData);
}
```

I have console the filename and blob file separately. it is showing. but when I am appending the blob and filename in formData, it is showing blank.

Please help me.

Comment: you cant console log formData .

Comment: then how will know the formData is appended or not?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to append blob data.

```
form.append("blob",blob, filename);
```

to console log. use this.

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

The console log should work if the data has appended.

Comment: Getting error: Property Entries does not exist on type formData.

Comment: I am using typescript.

Comment: try formData.forEach()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5694740/maneesh-rao Supress this error, just ignore it with ts-lint and it works for me, also gave this error about Entries doesn't exist too.

Answer (score 1):

In `console.log(formData)` is always showing null. Insted of that you can use `formData.get('PassKeyHere')` to get data.

Comment: Getting error: Property get does not exist on type formData.

Comment: `let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('test', '123');
  formdata.get('test');` I have tried above code its working fine in typescript.

Comment: I think some thing is problematic from your tsconfig or linting tool.

Comment: So Is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173337/discussion-between-baj9032-and-maneesh-rao).